# What kind of natural isomorphisms are alpha, lambda, and rho of a monoidal category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I've read about monoidal categories, and I understand them, however I'm still confused about calling the *associator*, *left unitor*, and *right unitor* natural isomorphisms.

Natural isomorphisms are just natural transformations, where every component has an inverse in the category itself.

But I wonder what kind of natural transformation they are? What are their domain and codomain? E.g. the left unitor:

$$
\lambda: (I ~\otimes ~ -) \cong -
$$

A natural transformation has a component for every object in the domain. I.e. it should also have a component for $(c,c)$ for any object $c$. But what would $\lambda(c ~\otimes ~ c)$ be? just an identity function?

The same applies to the associator, what e.g. would $\alpha(I \otimes I)$ be?

Comment: $\lambda$ is an isomorphism from the functor $I\otimes - $ to $1$. It means that you have $\lambda_A: I\otimes A \to A$ for every $A$

Comment: For the associator I think this is appropriate reading: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440758/understanding-associators-as-natural-transformations?rq=1

Comment: But what kind of functor is $1$? If $I \otimes -$ maps $(I,c)$ to $I \otimes c$, does $1$ map $(1,c)$ map to $c$? Why is it 1? It implies some kind of identity?

Comment: $1$ is the identity functor, which is a very simple functor. It takes everything to itself. $\lambda$ takes $I\otimes A$ to $A$ so that the element $I$ behaves like the unit of a group or a monoid under the product $\otimes$. (hence the name monoidal category!)

Comment: Ahh, I get it, once I thought about $I \otimes -$ being an endofunctor, it clicked.

Comment: @hgiesel: The functor $\otimes$ is the one that sends $(I,c)$ to $(I \otimes c)$. The functor $I \otimes -$ sends $c$ to $I \otimes c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiled from my comments above:

$\lambda$ is an isomorphism of the endofunctors $I\otimes$ and $1$, where $1$ is the identity functor. The map $\lambda_A$ goes from $I\otimes A$ to $A$ and tells us that $I\otimes A \cong A$.

This is just like the identity element of a monoid, which is where the name comes from.

Correspondingly, the other isomorphism tells us that $A\otimes I\cong A$.

The associator, which tells us that $\otimes$ is associative, is a bit more complicated, and if you want details about it you can see this question for instance: [Understanding associators as natural transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440758/understanding-associators-as-natural-transformations?rq=1)

Comment: I think in the second paragraph you mean "$I\otimes A \simeq A$", right?

Comment: @Pece I mean whatever symbol you think means isomorphism.

Comment: I was trying to point out a typo, the $I$ and $A$ should be swapped when talking about the left unitor.

Comment: @Pece with "other isomorphism" I'm pretty sure he's referring to the right unit or

Comment: @hgiesel I was talking about the first occurence, but Berci edited it since. (Maybe I should have done that directly.)