# The Id×(−⊗−) functor

Tags: category-theory, functors

In the the accepted answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440758/understanding-associators-as-natural-transformations?rq=1), Stefan Hamcke used this functor:

$$
Id×(−⊗−): C \times C \to C \times C
$$

It maps $(a,(a,a))$ to $(a, a \times a)$. But I wonder how this functor operates in other cases.

A functor has to map every object to a new object. 
But what would it do for $(a,b)$, or what would it do for $((a,b),c)$?

EDIT:

Okay I understood the statement in the original answer by Stefan Hamcke wrong. Now I understand that $Id(-\otimes -): C \times C \times C \to C$, however in that case:

What kind of triple in $C \times C \times C$ shows the associativity between $(z,(a,(b,c)))$ and $(z,((a,b),c))$?

I could imagine two new functors and their natural isomorphism:

$$
z \otimes (Id \times (- \otimes -)): \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}\\
z \otimes((- \otimes -) \times Id): \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}\\
\alpha_2: z \otimes (Id \times (- \otimes -)) \cong z \otimes((- \otimes -) \times Id)
$$

Is that the case? However in this case, the associator would need to a family of natural morphisms? Or is it okay, because $\alpha_2$ can be modelled as $z \otimes \alpha$?

Comment: The functor goes from $C\times C\times C$ to $C\times C$ and takes $(a,b,c)$ to $(a,b\otimes c)$. What do you mean by *other cases*?

Comment: Well he used the term "expanding the functor", which I understood as adding a a new functor at the start (Having now three functors). But I guess this makes a lot more sense.